# How to connect PostgreSQL database to Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Tags: linux, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, psycopg2, gcloud

I am trying to connect my Cloud SQL PostgreSQL databse to my Compute Engine instance, via psycopg2. My connection string as follows:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
                dbname=config('DATABASE'),
                user=config('USER'),
                password=config('PASSWORD'),
                host=config('HOST'),
                port=config('PORT')
            )
```

using port 5432 and the public IP address of the postgresql database. database, user, and password are all correct.
When I run this code via the compute instance i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot.add_cog(Profile(bot))
  File "/home/username/appname/Profile.py", line 22, in __init__
    port=config('PORT')
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user 
"mygcloudusername"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mygcloudusername"
```

For some reason it seems to be trying to connect via my gcloud username as the user, even though the correct user is specified in the connection string. Where have I gone wrong here? How can i connect this correctly?

Comment: Is Postgres deployed on Cloud SQL? If not, where is hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify if CloudSQL API is enabled [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/#enabling_the_api)?
As information, here is the documentation [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-instance) to create a PostgreSQL instance with the recommended configuration and setting.

I also recommend the documentation [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app) about 'Connecting to CloudSQL from external applications'. Here's a sample of code written in python [[4]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/cloudsql/main_postgres.py).